# How to get Media entity image (Entity Reference Field) URL in TWIG theme

Tags: theming, 8, entities, media

Apologies if this question has already been asked. However, in my research I found the answers have been for simple image fields which are in default install of Drupal 8. However, in order to have reusable media, I am using Media Entity and associated modules. The problem is I am not able to access image or its URL in TWIG template, where simple image fields work just fine.

While the code below works as expected if field_image is a simple Image type, but doesn't work if it is Entity Reference field.

```
<div class="header-title white overlay" style="background-image:url({{content.field_image.0}});">
```

In case of Entity Reference field, the output is fully escaped and breaks the structure of my theme. How can I get raw image or URL? I am not a programmer so I don't know how to write preprocessor code.

I am attaching configuration images for the Media Bundle I am using and the node configuration in which I'm using the two types of image fields.

*Media Bundle configuration*
[image]

*Node configuration. Note, **'field_image'** is default drupal image type, while **'field_image2'** is an entity reference field as configured in the Media bundle above.*
[image]

Please advice how to get this working. Thanks.

**Drupal Configuration**

- Drupal 8.3
- media_entity_browser-8.x-1.0-beta2
- media_entity-8.x-1.6
- media_entity_image-8.x-1.2
- embed-8.x-1.0-rc3
- entity-8.x-1.0-beta2
- inline_entity_form-8.x-1.0-beta1
- file_entity-8.x-2.0-beta3
- file-8.2.6
- field_formatter-8.x-1.0
- image_raw_formatter-8.x-1.x-dev
- image_url_formatter-image_url_formatter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this entity referenced image is controlled by Media, then you should let normal rendering occur:

```
{{ content.field_image2 }}
```

The rendering is then controlled by the field formatter, which will look to a display mode in Media, which is not dissimilar from Node display modes (default, teaser, etc).

Your filename would be something like:

```
media--media-bundle--display-mode.html.twig
media--media-bundle.html.twig
```

The first one is most specific, the second one would be the base for that media entity wherever it is used. I usually opt for the first one.

It is in this specific twig template where that code should live. The markup should be sourced there, instead of the referencing entity, in my opinion.

You could also do some preprocessing to solve this as well. Here is an example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 * @param $variables
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
  $bundle = $node->bundle();

  if ($bundle == 'landing_page' && $variables['elements']['#view_mode'] == 'hero') {
    $hero_image = $node->get('field_hero_image')->getValue();

    if (!empty($hero_image)) {
      $entity = Media::load($hero_image[0]['target_id']);
      $variables['hero_image'] = ImageStyle::load('landing_page_hero')->buildUrl($entity->field_image->entity->getFileUri());
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my respective template...

```
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }} style="background-image: url('{{ hero_image }}');"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can preprocess the media entity:

```
/**
 * Prepares variables for media templates.
 *
 * Default template: media.html.twig.
 *
 * @param array $variables
 *   An associative array containing:
 *   - media: An individual media for display.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_media(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\media_entity\MediaInterface $media */
  $media = $variables['elements']['#media'];

  $variables['media'] = $media;
  $variables['name'] = $media->label();

  // Helpful $content variable for templates.
  foreach (Element::children($variables['elements']) as $key) {
    $variables['content'][$key] = $variables['elements'][$key];
  }

  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'media';
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = Html::getClass('media-' . $media->bundle());

  if (!$media->isPublished()) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'unpublished';
  }

  if ($variables['elements']['#view_mode']) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = Html::getClass('view-mode-' . $variables['elements']['#view_mode']);

    if ($variables['elements']['#view_mode'] == 'hero') {
      $variables['hero_image'] = ImageStyle::load('hero')->buildUrl($media->field_image->entity->getFileUri());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answering. However, I got the following error when I tried the first code sample (with appropriate changes of course):

**_Error: Class 'Drupal\media\Media' not found in saha_preprocess_node()_**

I'm just trying to get a simple URL to the image, the problem is it always shows the image URL escaped in "" marks and withing the <article> tag. Is there any way I can get a simple image url? Where do I find the structure of the render array used by the Media / Media Image module?

Comment: You have to add the `use` statement at the top of the file to include the Media class, then this error will go away. `use Drupal\media\Media`

Comment: The above code also shows how to obtain the file uri.

Comment: Already tried that. I get the following error: **`Error: Class 'Drupal\media\Media' not found in saha_preprocess_node()`**

Comment: Update the code please

Comment: `
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
use Drupal\media\Media;
use Drupal\media_entity\MediaInterface;
function saha_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

    global $base_root;
    $node = $variables['node'];
    $bundle = $node->bundle();

    $hero_image = $node->get('field_image2')->getValue();
    if (!empty($hero_image)) {
      $entity = Media::load($hero_image[0]['target_id']);
      $variables['hero_image'] = ImageStyle::load('large')->buildUrl($entity->field_image->entity->getFileUri());
    }
} // end of function
`

Comment: This works but not for media image fields. 
**`if (!$node->field_image2->isEmpty()) {
      $image_media_entity = $node->field_image2->entity;
      $media_mime_type = $image_media_entity->field_mime_type;
      $variables['mime_type'] = [
        '#type' => 'processed_text',
        '#text' => $media_mime_type->value,
        '#format' => $media_mime_type->format,
        '#langcode' => $media_mime_type->getLangcode(),
      ];
    }`**

Comment: for media_entity I used `$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("media")->load($hero_image[0]['target_id']);`

Comment: Finally I got some where. Overrode the media.html.twig template in media_entity module by removing the <article> tags. By doing this, I get fully rendered image enclosed in an <img> tag with alt/title fields and image filters applied! I just have to print **{{ content.field_image2 }}** to get this. However, I am still unable to get basic url/alt fields. :(

Comment: I am also getting the `Class 'Drupal\media\Media' not found` error despite having `use Drupal\media\Media;` at the top of my file.

Comment: I couldnt get the `use` statement to work so I fully qualified the namespace at the method call. `$media = \Drupal\media\Entity\Media::load(...)`

Comment: How can the use statement not work? That’s core PHP.

Comment: Loading an image and then referencing $entity->>field_image doesn't really make sense...