# Render media entity image

Tags: 8, theming, media

I have a [media entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) target id and I want to render the image contained in it. I've loaded the media entity using Media::load, I was hoping to use something like render() on some rendererable array that I can extract/generate from that media entity object.
I found a somehow related question here: [How to get Media entity image (Entity Reference Field) URL in TWIG theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229402/how-to-get-media-entity-image-entity-reference-field-url-in-twig-theme), using ImageStyle::load, but I want to render the whole image with its defined attributes (alt, title or fields). Any suggestions please?

Comment: Why not just render the media object itself and let the field formatter on the image field do that work?

Comment: Well because it is an object and I need the renderable array of the media. `\Drupal::service('renderer')->render($media)`  render function only accepts an array, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to build a render array

```
$build = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('media')->view(‌$media, $view_mode);
```

and then place it unrendered in a template, Twig renders this automatically.

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for!  In fact, I wanted it rendered to get the whole html code from js. I could have passed only the media URI, but I needed the defined media attributes as alt for eg.

Answer (score 1):

Using the twig_tweak module, I found I could use:

```
<dd>{{ drupal_field('field_image', 'node') }}</dd>
```