# For each image uploaded in a node: get the url

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I'm begining with Drupal 8 and I want to get the url of the photos in the content I create to display them.

 The context is : a photograph upload pictures for a customer. This customer can see it on a page. To get this data in common I created a content for my shooting with an id.

 What i did is :

```php
$photos = $shooting->field_shooting_photos->target_id;
```

This allow me to get the id of every pictures uploaded.
Now I want to do a foreach on $photos in my .module that will return every url in an array. 
Then I will use this array in my Twig and do a foreach on it too to return every photos. 
I just can't figure out how to do, I think I will have to use something like that

```
$path = $photo_id->getFileUri();
```

but I can't figure out the syntax to get it into an array.
Thank you for your help!
**Solution :**
Here is what I did in case it can help someone :

```
$photosTest = $shooting->field_shooting_photos->referencedEntities();

$photoUrls = [];

foreach($photosTest as $media) {
  $photoUrls[] =
  $photoUrls[] = [
      'render' => [
         '#theme' => 'image_style',
         '#style_name' => 'medium',
         '#uri' => $media->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri()
       ],
       'href' => $media->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri(),
     ];
}
```

In my Twig file I render the array :

```
<div>
 {% for photo in photos %}
    <a href="{{ file_url(photo.href) }}">{{ photo.render }}</a>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving field_shooting_photos is a multi valued field of Files, this is how to generate your array of URI :

```
$photoUrls = [];
foreach($shooting->field_shooting_photos->referencedEntities() as $image) {
    $photoUrls[] = $image->getFileUri();
}
```

For media image :

```
$photoUrls = [];
foreach($shooting->field_shooting_photos->referencedEntities() as $media) {
    $photoUrls[] = $media->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri();
}
```

Note this will give you the File_id of the first image in the entite file reference list :

```
$shooting->field_shooting_photos->target_id;
```

NB : Best way is probably to generate render array or use built-in drupal themes, is none fit your needs, your may also [generate a custom field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-0).

Comment: thank you, i'm trying your solution but I get a Call to undefined method Drupal\media\Entity\Media::getFileUri(), I probably need to do a load first no ?

Comment: That's why i said "Giving field_shooting_photos is a multi valued field of *Files*" you get an iterable of Media, so you have to deal with medias instead of File. I update my answer in few time.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'm searching on still

Comment: I gave you the piece of caode for media references in this answer.

Comment: Yes I'm testing it and it's indeed working better now, yet I still get some errors such as `Trying to get property 'field_media_image'/'entity' of non-object` and `"0"/1"/"2"/"3" is an invalid render array key` -> This refer to the number of photos uploaded on the photograph page. And the kint of `$shooting->field_shooting_photos->referencedEntities()` I do have the field_media_image

Comment: Are you trying to render this array directly in your twig file ? That's not the way to render medias and/or images in drupal (have a look at my NB). Have a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/render-arrays and https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251844/render-media-entity-image.

Comment: Yeah my bad I forgot that I put this variable like this in my Twig yesterday. Imma fix that, thanks for the help!