# How do I render a Media Entity Reference image field in template_preprocess_node()?

Tags: media, 9

I'm altering the way images are rendered in the node preprocess function, and it is working exactly as expected for images in "Image" fields:

```
$field_view = $fields['field_image']->view(['label' => 'hidden']);
$field_view['#view_mode'] = 'full';
```

This results in the regular image array, so when I add it to my twig template, it gets rendered as an image tag.

However, we'd like to start using Media fields instead, and I can't figure out how to get the render array to come back with an image instead of just a text link. If I use the same thing for a media field, I just get a link with the image title as the text of the link:

```
$field_view = $fields['field_media_image']->view([
  'label' => 'hidden',
]);
```

This is what the 'file' image render array looks like; it renders as an image, which is what I want to get for the media image field:

```
#theme => "field"
#title => "Image"
#label_display => "hidden"
#view_mode => "full"
#language => "und"
#field_name => "field_image"
#field_type => "image"
#field_translatable => true
#entity_type => "node"
#bundle => "page"
#object => Drupal\node\Entity\Node (29)
#items => Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileFieldItemList (9)
#formatter => "image"
#is_multiple => false
#third_party_settings => array (0)
0 => array (6)
#cache => array (3)
#weight => 0
```

However, when I just use the same `view()` function on the media image field, I get this, which doesn't render as an image:

```
#theme => "field"
#title => "Media Image"
#label_display => "hidden"
#view_mode => "_custom"
#language => "und"
#field_name => "field_media_image"
#field_type => "entity_reference"
#field_translatable => false
#entity_type => "node"
#bundle => "page"
#object => Drupal\node\Entity\Node (29)
#items => Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList (9)
#formatter => "entity_reference_label"
#is_multiple => false
#third_party_settings => array (0)
0 => array (5)
#cache => array (3)
#weight => 0
```

I would guess that the reason this renders as a textual link is because of `#formatter => "entity_reference_label"` but whenI change this value, I continue to get the same output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Media entity image (Entity Reference Field) URL in TWIG theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229402/how-to-get-media-entity-image-entity-reference-field-url-in-twig-theme)

Comment: No. I'm not trying to render the field in the twig template, I'm trying to build a render array for the media field in my `template.theme` file. I understand how to do this for a regular Drupal image field, but not a media entity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($node->hasField('field_name') && $node->get('field_name')->entity) {

  // Set media entity.
  $mediaEntity = $node->get('field_name')->entity;

  // Get media image field.
  $mediaImage = $mediaEntity->get('field_media_image');

  // Get translated media image field.
  if ($mediaEntity->hasTranslation($langcode)) {
    $mediaImage = $mediaEntity->getTranslation($langcode)->get('field_media_image');
  }

  // Get media image entity.
  $mediaImageEntity = $mediaImage->entity;

  // Get image mime type.
  $mediaImageMimeType = $mediaImageEntity->getMimeType();

  // Get image file uri.
  $mediaImageEntityUri = $mediaImageEntity->getFileUri();

  // Set image url.
  $imageUrl = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generateString($mediaImageEntityUri);

  // Set image style url.
  if ($mediaImageMimeType !== "image/svg+xml") {
    $imageUrl = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->load('image_style_name')->buildUrl($mediaImageEntityUri);
  }

  $variables['imageUrl'] = $imageUrl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this; I'm not trying to just get the URL, although I suppose that would allow me to build my own image output. With the regular image field, I'm able to just use the `$field->view()` to generate a render array, and I'd like to use the same method (or equivalent) to render the media image field.

Answer (score 0):

Don't switch the field formatter, switch the entire entity view mode. I've done something similar with Paragraphs and media view modes, the following code is copy&paste from my project. It should be easy to adjust for nodes.

I just replaced the `#view_mode` key in the render array, but you have to do it for every single ER field value

```
function theme_preprocess_paragraph(array &$variables) {
  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
  if ($paragraph->hasField('field_image_viewmode')) {
    $imageViewMode = $paragraph->field_image_viewmode->value;
    if (!$paragraph->field_gallery->isEmpty()) {
      $mediaEntities = $paragraph->field_gallery->referencedEntities();
      foreach ($mediaEntities as $idx => $mediaEntity) {
        // this is the key line
        $variables['content']['field_gallery'][$idx]['#view_mode'] = $imageViewMode;
        // this operation is not cache-safe
        unset($variables['content']['field_gallery'][$idx]['#cache']['keys']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I recommend not doing this anymore. I'm now using [view_mode_switch](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_mode_switch) instead, which does the same thing with better code and with an UI (which basically  means it is documented for editors)